# Creating and update same object in a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, flow

I created an object in a flow, and then made a decision tree to update it if some value is true. The flow definitely reaches the update element, and it has all of the info necessary to update the record. But for some reason the record doesn't update. I wasn't able to add a screen to display a fault error. Anyone know why this might happen?

I was able to solve it by making my decision come before the create element, and then have two different create elements that do what is needed. But I did find it strange. My guess is that you can't create and update the same record in one flow?

Comment: Did you use the standard record create/update elements, or the fast create/update elements? Also, do you have a screenshot of the Flow, this helps with finding your problem.